# Blogger like application in Django

Tags: django, blogs

I am building a website that provide users,

- the feature to write their blogs on my website.
- These blogs will be read by other users on my website.

Here is my questions,

- I s there any app existing for this?, because all I have found are apps that allows one person or the admin(s) to write the blogs and not the users.

I don't mind using a plugin for blogger or some similar site, as long as it allows my users to write their blogs from my website without being navigated away.

> Recently I have been trying to build my own blogspot application, but
>   here I have stuck because I can't get to find how can I
>
> - save drafts and update them as the user makes
> - update changes
> - publish blogs
> - show them an onsite preview
>
> I have been going through tutorials and in the example where they tell
>   how to handle form data they just show how we can email it, they do
>   not give an example how we can update the backend data base or how we
>   can update an existing tuple and change it's status from, say draft to
>   published.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Other alternative:
https://github.com/flaab/pz-django-blog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to stick your blogging needs to Django, [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html) would be the way to go.

Otherwise, [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) (PHP) is just as simple and 1,2,3 to deploy and use.

---

#### *EDIT to answer comments*

Other Python blogging engine alternatives you can try:

- [Byteflow](http://byteflow.su/)
- [Zine](http://zine.pocoo.org/)
- [Papyrus](http://code.google.com/p/papyrus/)
- [Blohg](http://blohg.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is a content management system, and I just need a blogging engine. I have to stick to Django as I have developed other features already. Is there any app for making a blogging engine?

Although it offers a lot of other features as well, but I have already built a lot of my project in plain Django.

Comment: "content management system" is just a system that can manage content. think about blog posts as content => Mezzanine would be what you need.

Comment: Well I am a little new to it and I went through Mezzanine, and it said u can create a project in Mezzanine just like we do in Djnago, so how am I to use this for my already existing project. How can I use it as an app? Forgive me for my naivety, I am just a novice in using Django

Comment: depending on what your project is, you can either create a 3rd party module for Mezzanine, or just clone [Mezzanine](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/) and add your functionality. You can get more help on how to do it exactly on [Mezzanine User List](http://groups.google.com/group/mezzanine-users/topics)

Comment: I posted for more help on Mezzanine user list, but that was basically a dead end... Any other solution?

Comment: it does not seem like a dead end. you _can_ add `mezzanine.core` to your `installed apps` to resolve `mezzanine_tags`. Although you are not using the full Mezzanine feature set (not yet), it is a pretty solid blogging engine that you would not have to write yourself. In case you feel strongly about _not_ using Mezzanine, I added some alternatives to the answer.

Comment: It is not that I don't want to use Mezzanine, I have already spent so much time on searching for some solution. I would really like too speed things up, but somehow I am unable to see how I can use Mezzanine just for the blog. Actually there are many inter dependencies so If I use one feature I have to install a whole lot of others as well.